# How to set two different font style in one single line with prawn in Ruby on Rails generating a PDF file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

I have the following code:

```
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    pdf.text "Hello", :size => 22
    pdf.text "wold", :size => 12
```

But this code displays two lines.
I want to have the two text elements in one single line with the different font sizes as corresponding.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure, but this should help.  http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sandal/prawn/manual.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which tags are supported, but this might do the trick.

```
require 'prawn/format'
text "<font size=\"22\">Hello</font> <font size=\"12\">world</font>", inline_format => true
```

I found this answer [here](http://www.funonrails.com/2010/08/pdf-in-rails-using-prawn-library.html).

Comment: I'll give this a try, seems perfect !

Comment: when I type require 'prawn/format' it says file not found...!

Comment: @Angela - I don't know a thing about Prawn other than a little skimming to help people with their PDF problems.  Ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old one, but now you can use the formatted_text method that way :

```
    formatted_text [ 
                     { text: "Hello", size: 22 },
                     { text: "world", size: 12 }
                   ]
```

more info in the manual : http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf